# How can I make default fontstyle be one that the font likes?

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a small app that get a list of all the windows fonts. I can then choose one and display all its characters. All worked till I then found I had a problem, not all fonts have FontStyle:Regular. No problem I could do a check but this is where I run into a problem, when I start the system seems to have FontStyle:Regular as its default and I cannot change it so if I run the code below with text "Aharoni" selected in my combobox it falls over telling me that regular is not supported. How can I make it ignore the style or force the style to be one it uses like bold?

```
 var cvt = new FontConverter();
 Font fname = cvt.ConvertFromString(cmbobx_fontname.Text) as Font;
```

If I cannot do this then is it possible to get the styles that the choosen font will support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FontFamily class has a method to check if a style is available for the font - so rather than try to create a Font directly, first create a FontFamily instance & interate through the styles till you find one that is supported e.g.

```
  FontFamily fontf = new FontFamily("Aharoni");
  System.Drawing.FontStyle fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular;
  System.Drawing.Font font;
  if (fontf.IsStyleAvailable(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular))
    fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular;
  else if (fontf.IsStyleAvailable(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold))
    fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold;
  else if (fontf.IsStyleAvailable(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic))
    fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic;
  else if (fontf.IsStyleAvailable(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Strikeout))
    fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Strikeout;
  else if (fontf.IsStyleAvailable(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline))
    fs = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline;
  else
     throw new Exception("No Font Styles Available");
  font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontf, 10, fs);
```

You could iterate through the FontStyle enum - rather than use if/else as I have done.

Comment: That has worked but I adjusted slightly for my circumstances: FontFamily fname = new FontFamily(cmbobx_fontname.Text);
            FontStyle fs = FontStyle.Regular;
            Font font;

            FontStyle fstyle = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), cmbobx_style.Text, true);
            
            if (fname.IsStyleAvailable(fstyle))